# How can I concatenate a string without having to type it multiple times?

Tags: python, string-concatenation

Is there a way to write it so I don't have to type + str(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)) 3 times?

```
strip 1 ''.join([c for c in s if c not in ('!',' ',',',)])
strip2 = strip1 + str(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase))+ str(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase))+ str(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase))
return (strip2)
```

Answer (score 1):

use a `for loop`

```
strip2 = strip1 

for i in range(3):

    strip2 += str(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase))
```

Comment: you don't need `str()`

Answer (score 0):

list comprehension + range:

```
strip2 = strip1 + ''join([str(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)) for x in range(3)])
```